# Is it possible to backup Windows server 2008 R2 directly to a desktop/laptop?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to backup my Windows Server 2008 R2. Now what I want to do is, to transfer the data straight to another computer's drive. Is that possible? If yes, Can anyone provide me with the link or the steps on how i can do it?
It would be a big help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you already try? Where did you get stuck? etc etc.

Comment: My gut is telling me that you are not communicating what you are trying to accomplish  properly.  Backing up a computer is pretty easy, whether using Windows' built-in backup, or a 3rd party tool.  Are you trying to move the entire OS and applications to a laptop to be used there?

Comment: @Keltari I am not trying to backup a Windows computer, I am trying to backup a Windows Server. In case of server failure, I can use that backup to restore the data. What I am asking is, is it possible for me to backup my "Server data" and store directly to another computer or do I have to use a hard drive or something?

Comment: @DhrumitPatel you can back it up literally anywhere.

Comment: @Keltari So, in order to save that backup my server data straight to my laptop, what kind of physical connection do I have to do? Does a serial connection work? Will my laptop's drive be shown in my Server? Or do I have to share my laptop's hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your laptop and server are on the same network, you would create a share on the laptop that the user on the server has access to.  Using the built in Windows backup software on the server, you can backup to that share.